# Where are static libraries used by gcc or g++ stored, and how are they identified?

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, static-linking

I've been trying to determine if my Ubuntu (linux) system has -static libraries.  When would they be located, and what suffix would identify them?

Answer (score 1):

On debian-derived systems like Ubuntu, the static libraries that come with the system (installed by `apt`/`dpkg`, not by hand) usually go in `/usr/lib/<target-triplet>/` and have the suffix `.a`.

Example, on my x86-64 debian system:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFS.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImlib2.a
...
```

`apt-get install <package>-dev` will usually install such libraries in addition to the dynamic `*.so` ones.

There are still packages which install their libraries directly under `/usr/lib` though, eg. [libgraphicsmagick1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/libgraphicsmagick1-dev/filelist).

Compilers like `gcc` and `clang` will also install some "internal" libraries (`libstdc++`, etc) under `/usr/lib/<compiler-name>/...`, eg:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/libgcc.a
```

Other distros may follow different conventions; for instance, in rhel/centos, all the development libraries go under `/usr/lib64/` or `/usr/lib32/` and they're provided by `<package>-devel-*`. Compiling a file with `gcc -v` will always tell you where exactly the compiler is looking for libraries, whether static or dynamic.

Comment: THANK YOU. That's exactly what I needed!